# How can I differ "Office Standard 2016" and "Office Professional 2016 Plus" in C#

Tags: registry

I can get Microsoft office installed version with the help of registry, for example "Office 2016 (64 bit)".

But it does not give full version, like "Office 2016 Professional Plus" or "Office 2016 standard".

How can I identify them with the help of registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\InstalledPackages` subkeys (or the corresponding x64 key).

The first subkey should contain a standard value with the full version name.

---

*fun fact: those keys end with `0FF1CE`*